# target=_Blank in this php code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hope you're all well.

So here's what I want to do. I want to add to a review plugin in wordpress the possibility to open the page I want in a new window with the target="_blank" code.

I believe that's where the magic is happening, this is the original:

```
if ($show_morelink != '') {
                $review->review_text .= " <a href='".$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)."'>$show_morelink</a>";
            }
```

This is what I did without any success:

```
if ($show_morelink != '') {
                $review->review_text .= " <a href='".$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)."' target="_blank">$show_morelink</a>";
            }
```

I'm a beginner in PHP and I hope that someone can help me with this... I know it's not so hard.. I'm just missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `href='"` be `href="'`?

Comment: @DanielLisik that would be a syntax error in PHP vs a standards violation in HTML. Both are bad ;)

Comment: You can use `target='_blank'` or `target=\"_blank\"` --- comments take less room than "answers" ;-) --- and they're just as good.

Comment: ... unless you're in 'strict' standards mode - then you can't use either :P

Comment: Plus, using `target='_blank'` will save you two keystrokes, including not having to press on your "`Shift`" key twice; therefore saving 4 finger movements, time & energy. See how **"efficient"** it is? Call it `"Green"` coding. ;-)

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for taking the time to reply.I learned something today. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very much welcome. @ZaX - Remember to write `"Green"` code. It's the "little things that count". ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape your quotes.

Use the following

```
    $_morelink != '') {
        $review->review_text .= "<a href='".$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)."' target=\"_blank\">$show_morelink</a>";
    }
```

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for handling strings.

Comment: (or use single quotes - preferably the latter)

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is surrounded with double quotes, you are breaking out of them when you add in the target. You can either escape the quotes like this using a slash:

```
$review->review_text .= " <a href='".$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)."' target=\"_blank\">$show_morelink</a>";
```

Or change to using single quotes:

```
$review->review_text .= " <a href='".$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)."' target='_blank'>$show_morelink</a>";
```

*Edit*
A third way you could do it is surrounding the whole string in single quotes and remove the single quotes and periods form inside:

```
$review->review_text .= ' <a href="$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)" target="_blank">$show_morelink</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using doublequotes to denote php strings, so you can't use doublequotes for your html:

```
if ($show_morelink != '') {
    $review->review_text .= " <a href='".$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1)."' target='_blank'>$show_morelink</a>";
}
```

If you look at the HTML output you will see that both the `href` and `target` use single quotes now.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use single quotes for HTML code strings to improve readability.

```
if ($show_morelink != '') {
    $review->review_text .= '
      <a href="'.$this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1).'" target="_blank">'.$show_morelink.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: this will not work..  `'$show_morelink'` will be literally `$show_morelink` instead of the value of that variable

Comment: There is actually a technical difference between single and double quotes in PHP - one is a string literal the other isn't. Arguably I'd say it's better practice to use them in the way they're intended - literals for literals (keys in associative arrays and the like) and double-quotes when you need to interpolate strings with variables (outputting HTML for instance) - even if that means escaping your output strings.

Comment: sorry - i deleted my comment because i thought this comment was below on another answer that I commented on `;)`  yes, you're right.  it's typically bad practice to wrap strings in literal unless you really want literal.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers; most correctly pointing out the incorrect escaping of the quotations.

As it has not been mentioned yet `sprintf()` can also help with readability rather than having to concatenate strings.

```
$link = $this->get_jumplink_for_review($review,1);
$text = sprintf('<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', $link, $label);
```